# How does the hierarchical rank system in Amestris armed forces work?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

A lot of ranks are mentioned in the world of Fullmetal Alchemist (such as Colonel Mustang, Major Alex Louis Armstrong, etc.) but I've never known, what do these mean compared to themselves.

Can I find a descending order of all the character who's appearing in Fullmetal Alchemist (both in 2003 and 2009 series) with an order according to the rank in the army?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is compiled/arranged from [here](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/State_Alchemist) and [here](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Military_Ranks).

- Fuehrer General

  - Bradley
  - Grumman (Chapter 108)
- General

  - Roy Mustang - Flame Alchemist (epilogue)
- Lieutenant General

  - Grumman
  - Raven
  - Gardner
- Major General

  - Olivier Mira Armstrong
  - Hakuro
- Brigadier General

  - Basque Grand - Iron-Blood Alchemist
  - Roy Mustang - Flame Alchemist (ep. 45 2003 anime, chapter 108)
  - Maes Hughes (posthumous)
  - Clemin
  - Edison
  - Fessler
- Colonel

  - Roy Mustang - Flame Alchemist
  - Frank Archer
  - Henry Douglas
- Lieutenant Colonel

  - Alex Louis Armstrong - Strong Arm Alchemist (2003 anime)
  - Solf J. Kimblee - Crimson Alchemist/Red Lotus Alchemist (2003 anime)
  - Maes Hughes
  - Roy Mustang - Flame Alchemist (2003 anime)
- Major (automatic rank given to a State Alchemist)

  - Alex Louis Armstrong - Strong Arm Alchemist
  - Giolio Comanche - Silver Alchemist
  - Edward Elric - Fullmetal Alchemist
  - Solf J. Kimblee - Crimson Alchemist/Red Lotus Alchemist
  - Tim Marcoh - Crystal Alchemist
  - Isaac McDougal - Freezing Alchemist
  - Shou Tucker - Sewing-Life Alchemist
  - Miles
  - Maes Hughes (before ep. 13 2003 anime)
  - Roy Mustang (during war in Ishval)
- Captain

  - Juliet Douglas
  - Fokker
  - Buccaneer
  - Vato Falman (Chapter 108)
  - Maes Hughes (during the war in Ishval)
- First Lieutenant

  - Riza Hawkeye
  - Yoki
- Second Lieutenant

  - Maria Ross
  - Jean Havoc
  - Heymans Breda
  - Vato Falman (Chapter 65)
  - Henschel
  - Rebecca Catalina
  - Darius
  - Heinkel
  - Jerso
  - Zampano
  - Riza Hawkeye (at Eastern Headquarters)
- Warrant Officer

  - Vato Falman
  - Riza Hawkeye (after the war)
- Sergeant Major

  - Kain Fuery
- Sergeant

  - Denny Brosh
- Corporal (no named characters)
- Lance Corporal (no named characters)
- Private

  - Sheska
- Military Police (no named characters)

At the end of the 2003 anime, the rank of Fuhrer was removed, and in the Viz Manga version, the title used was President instead of Fuhrer.

Comment: please add the "Fuehrer General" (King Bradley)

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question and thought it was only asking for State Alchemists. Will fix now.

Comment: As noted in chapter 59 (and probably in a couple other places) State Alchemists have a rank _equivalent_ to Major, but that seems to be unrelated (to some extent) to their actual authority in the military (given Mustang's comment about only having the authority of a captain in the same chapter).

Comment: If you look at the second link, it says, "During the Ishval Civil War however, State Alchemists were not given the authority of a Major unless they earned it as a regular soldier would."

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Military_Ranks) is to the same wiki but to a page with all the ranks and people of those ranks including outside the state alchemists, it is noted that State Alchemists are an equivalent rank to Major, also the highest rank (Führer) is at the top.